# Angular 2 wait change on boolean to activate function

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make my function wait my variable change the value and then active my function but I don't want to use `setTimeout()`.

My ts:

```
if (this.dadoscadvp1.relacaoParentescoRespFam == 137) {
    //seta true o radio button1
    this.btn1 = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('radioBtn1').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: This is angular, you should use data binding, event listeners, or basically any of the tools Angular gives you to look for change. That's basically the whole point of Angular.

Comment: To the list given by @msanford you can add observables, which might be the right tool for you here.

Comment: @torazaburo That was the first one I thought of when reading this question, but I left it out because I assume it's simple user input. But very good point.